# How/Where do I put tags/keywords so that citar will find them?

Tags: bibtex, citation

I started using citar to manage my references.
Set up bibtex-library, folder for pdf's as well as notes.
Everything seems to work fine.

In the documentation of citar is says that the UI will show tags/keyswords if there are any for this entry and also the template for the display includes them as:
 `(suffix . "          ${=key= id:15}    ${=type=:12}    ${tags keywords:*}")`

I tried to put a key in the org-notes file, as well as in the bibtex entries but no matter where I put them, they dont seeem to show up.

Can somebody tell me the right way to add tags?

Comment: Adding them to the bibtex file as `keywords={...}` works but having the tags in the notes file would be nicer.